# Can't get NAV links to work, html code is correct

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hyperlink, nav

I'm building off a single page template.  I decided to add a second page that mirrors the main page.  I had to change the navbar link code to point to the main pages various sections (IE: instead of just `#about`, I made it `index.html#about`). These links are not working though. If I use "inspect" in Chrome and ctrl+click on the link in the code, it will work, so I'm thinking something in CSS is stopping this section from actually clicking the link.

The page with issues is [www.homexphoto.ca/pricing.html](http://www.homexphoto.ca/pricing.html)

Nav HTML Code

```
<div class="sidebarnav hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img id="topleftlogo" src="images/transparentlogowhite.png"> Home Expressions <br><em>Photography</em></a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <span class="rect"></span>
                            <span class="circle"></span>                          
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html#services">
                            <span class="rect"></span>
                            <span class="circle"></span>
                            Services
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html#pricing">
                            <span class="rect"></span>
                            <span class="circle"></span>
                            Pricing
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html#portfolio">
                            <span class="rect"></span>
                            <span class="circle"></span>
                            Portfolio
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html#about">
                            <span class="rect"></span>
                            <span class="circle"></span>
                            About
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html#contact">
                            <span class="rect"></span>
                            <span class="circle"></span>
                            Contact Us
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Nav CSS

```
/* Sidebar navigation secondary pages */
.sidebarnav {
  width: 22%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(12,12,12,0.9);
  z-index: 10;
}

.sidebarnav .logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 26px;
  background-color: #585858;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebarnav .logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 525;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid rgba(250,250,250,0.5);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 9px 2px 0px 2px;
  
}

.sidebarnav .logo em {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
   
}

.sidebarnav nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 60%;
  left: 60%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
}

.sidebarnav ul {
  margin-left: 45px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.sidebarnav li{
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.sidebarnav span{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.sidebarnav nav a{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.sidebarnav nav a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
.sidebarnav nav a:hover, nav .active-section {
  color: #fff;
}
.sidebarnav nav a:hover span, nav .active-section span{
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.sidebarnav nav .active-section .rect{
  width: 30px;
}
.sidebarnav nav .active-section .circle{
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sidebarnav .social-icons {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;  
  bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebarnav .social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.sidebarnav .social-icons li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.sidebarnav .social-icons li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.sidebarnav .social-icons li a:hover {
  color: #45489a;
}
```

Am I missing something simple here?  The template Im using also has Javascript which Im trying not to touch as Im not there yet in skill.  I'm hoping that isnt blocking this somehow.

Cheers

EDIT - if I right click the sidebar nav links and 'open in a new tab' they work!  But the single click seems disabled?

Comment: You should use CTRL+M inside function on the page edit. let us find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I right-click and choose "open link in new window", it works as expected, the new page opens, so the links are correct.

I would suspect that there is some javascript that contains "preventDefault()" for the links in order to perform a scrolling animation or something similar.

In fact, this seems to be a template for a one-pager - the links do work (using animated scrolling) on the `index.html` page...

So, have a look at the JS files and search for "preventDefault"...

---

Addition after comments: This piece of code has helped me to solve a similar problem a while ago:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(window.location.hash) {
            var hash = window.location.hash;
            $( 'a[href=' + hash + ']' ).click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes, I'll do that.  Never worked with JS before but you're right.  It's a one pager template.

Comment: ```$('#nav-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#main-nav').toggleClass("open");
        });
```
Found this

Comment: well, so the problem is that you want (?) that animation for same-page links, but need the links to work regularly when addressing other pages...

Comment: Yeah I don't need the link animation for secondary pages, just trying to keep the same look but just go back to a regular nav bar that works properly.

Comment: I added some jQuery code to my answer, hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for that.  Just tried it with no luck.  I think I'll get rid of the side navigation and add a simple link to return to the index page.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that its in the JS though, if it was simple html and css, I didn't want to give up but java is still something I need to learn more.

Comment: Updated Fix - it may not be perfect but in the html, I just deleted any scripts for js and it seems to have worked!

Comment: hmm - I wouldn't rely on that, the other might be needed for the page to work... Try to only  erase or (better) comment out (by inserting `//`at the beginning of that line) the line that contains the `preventDefault`